# Is there something in PHP similar to Option Explicit in VB

Tags: php, variables, declaration

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Strict mode in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3193072/strict-mode-in-php)

I am doing a big project in PHP. In PHP you do not need to declare variables. This is causing a lot of problems for me.

In Visual Basic 6, the Option Explicit statement makes it mandatory to declare variables. Is something similar available in PHP?

Comment: what about undefined functions inside if  else that not running in run time?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you turn on E_NOTICE error messages, PHP will tell you about *uninitialized* variables:

```
ini_set("error_reporting", E_ALL);
```

Uninitialized is a little bit different than undeclared, but it should give you a similar effect.

Comment: +1 It's also worth noting that `E_ALL` does *not* include `E_STRICT`. So I would do `ini_set("error_reporting", E_ALL & E_STRICT);`. Also worth noting; You can set `error_reporting` in `php.ini` or in your Apache virtual host definition using `php_value`.

Answer (score 4):

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

throws a notice when you attempt to use an undefined variable

a more general tip: use functions instead of global code, and make them small (max. 20 lines). Since variables are local to functions, there's less chance to forget or misspell a variable name.

Answer (score 1):

Increasing the [error reporting level](http://docs.php.net/error_reporting) only affects php's behaviour when an undefined variable/element is used as rvalue, like `echo $doesnotexist;`.
But [`option explicit on`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y9341s4f%28VS.80%29.aspx) also prohibits the use of undeclared variables as lvalue

```
Option Explicit On
Dim x As Integer
x = 10
y = 11 ' error, variable is not declared
```

There's no similar option or config parameter in php.

Comment: There _could_ have been a keyword declared in php5, esp. for classes/members, but there wasn't.