# PHP and undefined variables strategy

Tags: php, variables, undefined

I am a C++ programmer starting with PHP. I find that I lose most of the debugging time (and my selfesteem!) due to undefined variables. From what I know, the only way to deal with them is to watch the output at execution time.

Are other strategies to notice these faults earlier (something like with C++ that a single compile gives you all the clues you need)?

Comment: This isn't really a direct answer to your question, but having so much trouble with undefined variables implies you are producing spaghetti code. With more organised OO code, it is easier to see the scope and lifespan of variables.

Comment: I understand your concern however, coming from C++ it seems to me you would be responsible with declaring variables prior to usage.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a common complaint with PHP.  Here are some ideas:

1. Use a [code analysis tool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/378959/is-there-a-static-code-analyzer-like-lint-for-php-files).  Many IDEs such as [NetBeans](http://netbeans.org/) will help also.
2. *Just run the code.*  PHP doesn't have an expensive compilation step like C++ does.
3. Use unit testing.  Common side effects include: better code.
4. Set [`error_reporting(-1)`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php), or the equivalent in your [ini file](https://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-reporting).
5. Get [xdebug](http://xdebug.org/).  It's not preventative, but stack traces help with squishing bugs.
6. [`isset()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php), [`=== null`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) (identity operator), and guard clauses are your friends.

Loose and dynamic typing are a feature of the language.  Just because PHP [isn't strict about typing](http://www.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php) doesn't mean you can't be.  If it really bugs you and you have a choice, you could try Python instead—it's a bit stricter with typing.

Comment: +1, for the `error_reporting(-1);`, didn't knew about that (minus) one!

Answer (score 6):

Log your E_NOTICE messages to a text file. You can then process logs with automated scripts to indicate files and lines where these are raised.

Comment: This doesn't really fix the issue IMO. What is needed is a different working routine that prevents those notices from coming up in the first place.

Comment: That's for sure. Browsing/parsing logs is just an 'improved' version of 'watching the output' to catch errors coming from legacy code, or those that somehow slipped into new code.

Comment: no website should ever throw out errors, NEVER - atlest redirect the user to a static error page, imagine if you went on youtube and seen this in header `"PHP Notice: X:/server/server_mounts/primary/public/data/index.php The variable $youtube_global_credit_card_details was not found"` - just be a terrable thing especially for the general public. professionalism is always an approach you should take. :)

Comment: Agree on that. Fortunately you can log errors without displaying them to the user.

Answer (score 5):

No. In PHP, you can only know a variable doesn't exist when you try to access it.

Consider:

```
if ($data = file('my_file.txt')) {
    if (count($data) >= 0)
        $line = reset($data);
}
var_dump($line);
```

You have to restructure your code so that all the code paths leads to the variable defined, e.g.:

```
$line = "default value";
if ($data = file('my_file.txt')) {
    if (count($data) >= 0)
        $line = reset($data);
}
var_dump($line);
```

If there isn't any default value that makes sense, this is still better than `isset` because you'll warned if you have a typo in the variable name in the final `if`:

```
$line = null;
if ($data = file('my_file.txt')) {
    if (count($data) >= 0)
        $line = reset($data);
}
if ($line !== null) { /* ... */ }
```

Of course, you can use `isset`<sup>1</sup> to check, at a given point, if a variable exists. However, if your code relies on that, it's probably poorly structured. My point is that, contrary to e.g. C/Java, you cannot, at compile time, determine if an access to a variable is valid. This is made worse by the nonexistence of block scope in PHP.

<sup>1</sup> Strictly speaking, `isset` won't tell you whether a variable is set, it tell if it's set and is not null. Otherwise, you'll need `get_defined_vars`.

Comment: And what good does that do? He's replaced a visible runtime complaint with an access to a variable with a garbage value, now perhaps giving a silent bug rather than a diagnosed one. (0 is garbage [as is any other choice of initializing constant] if it isn't the value the variable is supposed to have at at that point in the code). What he needs is *static* analysis to determine where variables are used but not initialized.  Too bad there aren't more PHP analysis tools.

Comment: @Pekka I call that accessing. I'll edit to make it more clear.

Comment: @Ira It was just an example of a code path that would lead to the variable always being defined. I agree with you.

Comment: +1: Coming from a C++ background, this should be habit already.  And this will prevent tons of bugs.  As for 0 being a garbage value, it's not at all since you know that if it's 0, it wasn't defined yet.  I personally declare all variables prior to using them.  It's a good habit and will rarely lead to bugs (so long as you don't do anything stupid like declare a int then later re-assign an object)...

Comment: @ircmaxell: That's crazy.  Most good compilers (PHP is not one of these) will diagnose an unassigned variable arriving by some control flow path to a use of that variable.   If you *set* the variable to garbage, you simply make it impossible for the compiler to help you.

Comment: @Ira No one's saying "hey, it gave a notice – let's just initialize the var to garbage to shut it up". What I'm saying is you should restructure your flow so that the variable is always defined. Once in a while, it will mean you will have to initialize it to an otherwise invalid, special flag value. In this case, you can argue it would be the same as using `isset`, but it's not. If you do `isset($variableWithTypo)`, you'll have a bug, if you do `if ($variableWithTypo === null)` (where `null` is the special "flag value"), you'll also have a bug, but at least you get a notice.

Comment: Nobody is arguing that you shouldn't write code the *correctly* initializes the variables (whether you do that with explicit assignments or do it in such a way that a single assignment dominates all references). The discussion appeared to be about the case where the coder wasn't perfect (I'm not). In that case, you *want* the compiler's help, and the suggestion appeared to be "just initialized to a garbage value before you do anything else". That's my objection.   *If* you can find a "garbage" value that will always makes the application complain, maybe that's OK.  Zero isn't that value.

Comment: @Ira Yes, `0` doesn't have any meaning, but `(mt_rand(1,2) == 1)` doesn't have any meaning either, yet I don't see you protesting. Anyway, I'll edit the answer with a real world example...

Answer (score 2):

> From what I know the only way to deal with them is to watch the output at execution time.

Not really: To prevent these notices from popping up, you just need to make sure you initialize variables before accessing them the first time. We (sadly IMO) don't have variable declaration in PHP, but initializing them in the beginning of your code block is just as well:

```
$my_var = value;
```

Using phpDocumentor syntax, you can also kind of declare them to be of a certain a type, at least in a way that many IDEs are able to do code lookup with:

```
/** @desc optional description of what the variable does
    @var int */
$my_var = 0;
```

Also, you can (and sometimes need to) use `isset()` / `empty()` / `array_key_exists()` conditions before trying to access a variable.

[I agree this sucks big time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960509/isset-and-empty-make-code-ugly) sometimes, but it's necessary. There should be no notices in finished production code - they eat up performance even if displaying them is turned off, plus they are very useful to find out typos one may have made when using a variable. (But you already know that.)

Answer (score 2):

Just watch not to do operations that requires the variable value when using it the first time, like the concatenate operator, `.=`.

If you are a C++ programmer you must be used to declare all variables. Do something similar to this in PHP by zeroing variables or creating empty array if you want to use them.

Pay attention to user input, and be sure you have registered `globals off` and check inputs from $_GET and $_POST by isset().

You can also try to code classes against structural code, and have every variable created at the beginning of a class declaration with the correct privacy policy.

You can also separate the application logic from the view, by preparing all variables that have to be outputted first, and when it goes to display it, you will be know which variables you prepared.

Answer (score 2):

During development stages use

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

which will show every error that has caused, all NOTICE errors, etc.

Keep an eye on your `error_log` as well. That will show you errors.

Use an error reporting system, example:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php

```
class ErrorReporter
{
    public function catch($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline)
    {
        if($errno == E_USER_NOTICE && !defined('DEBUG'))
        {
            // Catch all output buffer and clear states, redirect or include error page.
        }
    }
}

set_error_handler(array(new ErrorReporter,'catch'));
```

A few other tips is always use `isset` for variables that you may / may not have set because of a `if` statement let’s say.

Always use `if(isset($_POST['key']))` or even better just use `if(!empty($_POST['key']))` as this checks if the key exists and if the value is *not* empty.

Make sure you know your comparison operators as well. Languages like C# use `==` to check a Boolean state whereas in PHP to check data-types you have to use `===` and use `==` to check value states, and single `=` to assign a value!

Answer (score 2):

Unless I'm missing something, then why is no one suggesting to structure your page properly?  I've never really had an ongoing problem with undefined variable errors.

**An idea on structuring your page**

Define all your variables at the top, assign default values if necessary, and then use those variables from there. That's how I write web pages and I never run into undefined variable problems.

Don't get in the habit of defining variables only when you need them. This quickly creates spaghetti code and can be very difficult to manage.

> [image]
>
> No one likes spaghetti code

If you show us some of your code we might be able to offer suggestions on how you can better structure it to resolve these sorts of errors. You might be getting confused coming from a C background; the flow may work differently to web pages.

Comment: It doesn’t matter where your variables are defined — a simple typo later in the code creates a new variable with a potentially unexpected value. The only way to deal with this is to (a) run every code path and then (b) watch the log files. Although that works, the OP was looking for a better way. C and other languages (even dynamic ones like Python and JavaScript) have tools like compilers and linters that can detect undefined variables, and it saves a lot of time. Finally, not all PHP developers are writing “pages” or web front-ends.

Answer (score 1):

Good practice is to define all variable before use, i.e., set a default value:

> $variable = default_value;

This will solve most problems. As suggested before, use [Xdebug](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xdebug) or built-in debugging tools in editors like [NetBeans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NetBeans).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to hide the error of an undefined variable, then use `@`. Example: `@$var`

Answer (score 0):

I believe that various of the [Code Coverage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_coverage) tools that are available for PHP will highlight this.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I try and set variables, even if it's with an empty string, array, Boolean, etc. Then I use a function such as `isset()` before using them. For example:

```
$page_found = false;

if ($page_found==false) {
    // Do page not found stuff here
}

if (isset($_POST['field'])) {
    $value = $_POST['field'];
    $sql = "UPDATE table SET field = '$value'";
}
```

And so on. And before some smart-ass says it: I know that query's unsafe. It was just an example of using `isset()`.

Answer (score 0):

I really didn't find a direct answer already here. The actual solution I found to this problem is to use [PHP Code Sniffer](https://github.com/squizlabs/PHP_CodeSniffer) along with this awesome extension called [PHP Code Sniffer Variable Analysis](https://github.com/sirbrillig/phpcs-variable-analysis).

Also the regular PHP linter (php -l) is available inside PHP Code Sniffer, so I'm thinking about customizing my configuration for regular PHP linting, detecting unused/uninitialized variables and validating my own code style, all in one step.

My very minimal PHPCS configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ruleset name="MyConfig">
    <description>Minimal PHP Syntax check</description>
    <rule ref="Generic.PHP.Syntax" />
    <rule ref="VariableAnalysis" />
</ruleset>
```