# Laravel 5.3 Global `strict_types`

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, php-7

We want to declare the `<?php declare(strict_types=1);` to all pages of our Laravel project.

The question is how to make it global so that we don't need to declare it file by file?

Comment: No you can't declare it globally.

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37111470/enabling-strict-types-globally-in-php-7) for more information.