# 'strict_types=1' does not seem to work in a function

Tags: php, typing

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);
$a = 1;
$b = 2;
function FunctionName(int $a, int $b)
{
    $c = '10'; //string
    return $a + $b + $c;
}
echo FunctionName($a, $b);
?>
```

I expected `FunctionName($a, $b)` will print an error, but it does not print an error message.

As you can see, I added a string(`$c`) to an int(`$a+$b`), and declared `strict_types=1`.

why can't I get an error message?

Comment: `declare(strict_types=1);` not possible

Comment: @AlivetoDie could you explain me why is it impossible?

Comment: given in the duplicate link already:- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37111470/enabling-strict-types-globally-in-php-7

Comment: @AlivetoDie I think you have misunderstood the question you linked to. That user was asking if they could automatically enable this directive across all files (which you can't); enabling it at the top of one file is exactly what you *can* do, and the code in this question is perfectly valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Strict types" mode only checks types at specific points in the code; it does not track everything that happens to the variable.

Specifically, it checks:

- the parameters given to the function, if type hints are included in the signature; here you are giving two `int`s to a function expecting two `int`s, so there is no error
- the return value of the function, if a return type hint is included in the signature; here you have no type hint, but if you had a hint of `: int`, there would still be no error, because the result of `$a + $b + $c` is indeed an `int`.

Here are some examples that *do* give errors:

```
declare(strict_types=1);
$a = '1';
$b = '2';
function FunctionName(int $a, int $b)
{
    return $a + $b;
}
echo FunctionName($a, $b);
// TypeError: Argument 1 passed to FunctionName() must be of the type integer, string given
```

Or for a return hint:

```
declare(strict_types=1);
$a = 1;
$b = 2;
function FunctionName(int $a, int $b): int
{
    return $a . ' and ' . $b;
}
echo FunctionName($a, $b);
// TypeError: Return value of FunctionName() must be of the type integer, string returned
```

Note that in the second example, it is not the fact that we calculated `$a . ' and ' . $b` that throws the error, it's the fact that we *returned* that string, but our promise was to return an integer. The following will *not* give an error:

```
declare(strict_types=1);
$a = 1;
$b = 2;
function FunctionName(int $a, int $b): int
{
    return strlen( $a . ' and ' . $b );
}
echo FunctionName($a, $b);
// Outputs '7'
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Now I understand it more clearly.