# PHP type hinting is being ignored, no TypeError exception is thrown

Tags: php, types, casting, function-signature

I just debugged some PHP 7.1 code where I'd forgotten to remove a `(bool)` cast on the return value, but the function had a declared return type of `int`:

```php
function get_foo(): int {
    $val = get_option('foo');
    return (bool) $val;
}

$foo = get_foo();
```

[Test the code here.](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/849efac9c7c5031582808bb9bb6a2c516d4d71ee)

It's easy to cast between `bool` and `int`, of course, but **why didn't this throw a [TypeError](http://php.net/manual/en/class.typeerror.php)**?

> There are three scenarios where a TypeError may be thrown. ... The second is where a value being returned from a function does not match the declared function return type.

The same behaviour is exhibited for typed function parameters.

```php
function get_foo(string $foo): int {
    $val = get_option($foo);
    return (bool) $val;
}

// no TypeError!
$foo = get_foo(34);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the `strict_types` directive for type hinting to work properly

Quoting from [PHP 7 New Features](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php)

> To enable strict mode, a single declare directive must be placed at the top of the file. This means that the strictness of typing for scalars is configured on a per-file basis. This directive not only affects the type declarations of parameters, but also a function's return type (see return type declarations, built-in PHP functions, and functions from loaded extensions.

With that, you should do this.

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

function get_option_foo() : int {
    $val = get_option('foo'); // Returns a string that can be parsed as an int
    return (bool) $val;
}

$foo = get_option_foo();
```

Try this once again, you will receive an `Uncaught TypeError Exception`

Comment: Ah! How did I miss that? Thank you.

Comment: Also, the fact that [this can't be done globally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37111470/enabling-strict-types-globally-in-php-7) is depressing to this relatively recent user of PHP.

Comment: For me, per file basis is good enough as it gives enough flexibility. After all, strict typing is an extra for PHP. Turning on STRICT_TYPING globally on a server would break a lot of existing PHP Applications that were not coded in conformity to strict typing.... :)

Comment: Would've saved me this bug just now! But I'm sure I'll come round to a reasonable view of things. :p