# PHP Sending Mail, but not redirecting. Stuck on white php page

Tags: php, redirect, phpmailer

My php form is getting stuck, sends mail but doesnt redirect. I'm using the same base portion of the code on another page and it does redirect fine. Differences between the two - this one has functions in it, this one is longer. Cant find why its not redirecting. I've tried exit, I've tried switching mail out of the if condition for the redirect. ive tried ob_start and ob_end_flush. Not sure where to go

`
<?php

```
  function updateArrayValues(&$array) {
  foreach ($array as &$value) {
    $value = ($value == 0) ? "No" : "Yes";
   }
 }

 function combineAndPrintArrays($names, $values, $final) {
$result = "";
 for ($i = 0; $i < count($names); $i++) {
$final[$i]= $names[$i] . ": " . $values[$i] . PHP_EOL;
 }
$result = implode("<br>", $final);
return $result;
 }


require __DIR__.'/../vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
require __DIR__.'/../vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer/src/Exception.php';
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;
require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';

$dotenv = Dotenv\Dotenv::createImmutable(__DIR__);
$dotenv->load();
global $password;
global $mailerEmail;
$mailerEmail = $_ENV['EMAIL_USERNAME'];
$password = $_ENV['EMAIL_PASSWORD'];








 if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

 // CLIENT INFO
$name = $_POST["name"];
 $phone = $_POST["phone"];
 $email = $_POST["email"];
 $address = $_POST["address"];

 // APPT INFO
 $apptDate = $_POST["EmailDate"];
 $apptTime = $_POST["EmailTime"];
 $initialClean = $_POST["EmailPrice"];
 $discountClean = $_POST["EmailDiscount"];

 //HOUSE INFO
 $bedroom = $_POST["bedroom"];
 $bathroom = $_POST["bathroom"];
 $halfbathroom = $_POST["halfbathroom"];
 $sqft = $_POST["sqft"];

  if($sqft == 1){
   $sqft = "Under 1000 Sq Ft";
}else if($sqft == 2){
   $sqft = "Between 1000 & 2500 Sq Ft";
 } else {
   $sqft = "Over 2500 Sq Ft";
 }

   //CLEAN INFO
   $servicetype = $_POST["servicetype"];

  if($servicetype == 1){$servicetype = "Basic Clean";}
 elseif($servicetype == 2){$servicetype = "Deep Clean"; }
   elseif($servicetype == 3){$servicetype = "Moving Clean";}
 elseif($servicetype == 4){$servicetype = "Party Clean";}

 $frequency = $_POST["frequenc"];

if ($frequency == '0.1') {
$frequency = "Monthly";
} elseif ($frequency == '0.2') {
$frequency = "Weekly";
} elseif ($frequency == '0.15') {
$frequency = "Bi-Weekly";
} else {
$frequency = "One Time";
$discountClean = "n/a";
  }

 // ADDONS



 $AddOnFinal = [];
$addInsideFridge = $_POST["insideFridge"];

 $addInsideCabinets = $_POST["insideCabinets"];
$addMakeBed = $_POST["makeBeds"];
 $addGrout = $_POST["grout"];
 $addDishes = $_POST["dishes"];
 $addTrashcans = $_POST["insideTrashcan"];
  $addDrawers = $_POST["insideDrawers"];
  $addFullFridge = $_POST["insideFullFridge"];
  $addWindows = $_POST["Windows"];

 $ValueArray = [$addInsideFridge, $addInsideCabinets, $addMakeBed,
            $addGrout, $addDishes, $addTrashcans, $addDrawers, $addFullFridge, $addWindows];

$NameArray = ['Inside Fridge', 'Inside Cabinets',  'Make Beds',
'Grout',  'Dishes',  'Inside Trash Cans',  'Inside Drawers',
'Inside Full Fridge',  'Windows'];

updateArrayValues($ValueArray);
$AddOns = combineAndPrintArrays($NameArray, $ValueArray, $AddOnFinal);

$message = $_POST["message"];



$mail = new PHPMailer(true);

try {
// $mail->SMTPDebug = SMTP::DEBUG_SERVER;  
$mail->SMTPDebug = 0;                    
$mail->isSMTP();                                            
$mail->Host       = 'mail.x.com';                     
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                                   
$mail->Username = $mailerEmail;
$mail->Password = $password;                              
$mail->SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_STARTTLS;            
$mail->Port       = 587;                                    

//Recipients
$mail->setFrom($mailerEmail, 'Mailer'); 
$mail->addReplyTo($email, $name);
$mail->addAddress('x@gmail.com');

$header = "Quote Submission from $email";

//Content
$mail->isHTML(true);                                  //Set email format to HTML
$mail->Subject = $header;
$mail->Body    = "<b>Name: </b> $name <br><b>Phone: </b>$phone<br>
<b>Email:</b> $email<br><br>

<b>Service Type:</b> $servicetype   &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;    <br><b>Frequency:</b> $frequency<br>
<b>Appointment:</b> $apptDate &nbsp;&nbsp; $apptTime<br>
<b>Intial Clean:</b> $$initialClean  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;     
<br><b>Discounted Clean:</b> $$discountClean<br><br>

<b>Address:</b> $address &nbsp;&nbsp;  <br><b>Sq.ft.:</b> $sqft<br>
<b>Rooms:</b> $bedroom    &nbsp;&nbsp;  <b>Bathrooms:</b> $bathroom   &nbsp;&nbsp;    
<b>Half-Baths:</b> $halfbathroom<br>
<br>
<b>Message:</b><br> $message<br>
<br>
<b>Add-Ons:</b> <br>$AddOns";



if($mail->send()){
    
    header("Location:https://www.x.com/successsub.html");
    
    exit();
};

} catch (Exception $e) {
echo "Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: {$mail->ErrorInfo}";
}

}


?>`
```

Comment: `$success` is undefined, so your `if` does not execute. (`$sucess`, which you do define, is a different variable.) Closing as typo. (You might want to follow [these tips](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3193072/strict-mode-in-php) to make sure you catch these kinds of errors.)

Comment: consider this: if($mail->send())
i get the same result of not redirecting

Comment: the issue was whitespace before the php opening tab - who could have guessed it

Comment: That should have generated a warning message. Perhaps you don't have php configured to output or log warnings and errors?

Comment: Right. once i had it correct in the other i turned it off and thought it'd pop off without a hitch, but im new to php so something so silly was in my way.

Comment: You always need some form of error handling enabled. In a live environment you should use logging to a file instead of direct output.